# Delete duplicate records based on some criteria - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking up to get this result in SQL SERVER with this input :

- Input:

  | ID | Date | Name | Backup |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | 04/12/2020 | A | Success |
  | 2 | 04/12/2020 | A | Success |
  | 3 | 04/12/2020 | B | Failed |
  | 4 | 04/12/2020 | B | Success |
  | 5 | 04/12/2020 | B | Success |
  | 6 | 04/12/2020 | C | Success |
  | 7 | 04/12/2020 | D | Failed |
  | 8 | 04/12/2020 | D | Failed |
  | 9 | 04/12/2020 | D | Failed |
  | 10 | 04/12/2020 | E | Success |
  | 11 | 04/12/2020 | F | Success |
- Result

  | ID | Date | Name | Backup |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | 04/12/2020 | A | Success |
  | 4 | 04/12/2020 | B | Success |
  | 6 | 04/12/2020 | C | Success |
  | 7 | 04/12/2020 | D | Failed |
  | 10 | 04/12/2020 | E | Success |
  | 11 | 04/12/2020 | F | Success |
- Where the status is "FAILED", and the previous and next row are "Success": not display the row
- Where the status is "Failed"  and the previous or next row or both are "Failed": display just one of the Failed rows
- do not display duplicates when the status is "Success"

This is what i have tried:

```
    SELECT a.*
FROM [DB_QPB].[dbo].[Sheet1$] a

INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT   name, [Backup],
    MIN(id) as id
    
  FROM [DB_QPB].[dbo].[Sheet1$] 
  GROUP BY NAME, [Backup]
  
) AS b
  ON a.name = b.name 
  AND a.id = b.id 
  and a.[Backup]= b.[Backup]
  --order by id
and  
(SELECT  LEAD(p.[Backup]) OVER(ORDER BY p.id) NextValue
FROM [DB_QPB].[dbo].[Sheet1$] p) !=  'Failed'
 and 

(SELECT  LEAD(p.[Backup]) OVER(ORDER BY p.id) NextValue
FROM [DB_QPB].[dbo].[Sheet1$] p)!= 'failed'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that if there is a row with `Success` show it else show `Failed`

You can use the window function `row_number()` and `ORDER BY`  with `Success` having higher priority over `Failed`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT *,
                  RN = ROW_NUBMER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date], [Name]
                                              ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Backup] = 'Success'
                                                            THEN 1
                                                            ELSE 2
                                                            END)
           FROM   yourtable
       ) D
WHERE  D.RN = 1
```